iOS AVPlayer Dims other UI Views, how do I prevent this?
I am using an AVPlayer to play a video. There is a play button on top of the AVPlayer, but iOS dims this play button, meaning it's not white anymore, but gray.
I am aware of this behaviour and in some cases it can be useful, but can anybody tell me how to disable the dimming?
Thanks a lot!

I'm seeing the same thing, and looking for a solution. Do you think this is an iOS bug?

I'm noticing that this behavior only occurs on certain videos. I'm also noticing the white text in the status bar is also changing color in exactly the same manner. My guess is that iOS is doing this automatically to increase readability.

Yes, iOS is doing this on purpose. You can also see it in the Instagram app on reels. However, Instagram found a way to keep some of the video overlays white and has some dimmed. So it must be somehow possible.
